# Running Someone else's Source Code

Tags: java, compiler-errors

So I found source code for a game I want to examine (read, not a virus). The link is in the description of the video below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AA1XpWHhxw0

So I downloaded it and extracted the files. The game should be run from `/src/com/neet/DiamondHunter/Main/Game.java`.

I then tried to run Game.java from the command line:

```
C:\...Diamond Hunter\src\com\neet\DiamondHunter\Main> javac Game.java
```

and get the following error:

```
Game.java:15: error: cannot find symbool
        window.add(new GamePanel());
                       ^
symbol:    class GamePanel
location:  class Game
```

I cannot for the life of me, figure out what the problem is.

Both **Game.java** and **GamePanel.java** exist, are in the same package, in the same folder, but the compiler doesn't find `GamePanel` when running `Game`.

I have had this problem with code I've downloaded before. The program is not an applet, and I haven't been misspelling things. Could someone help me run these files, or give me some insight into what is/isn't happening?

Comment: You must supply the classpath.

Comment: (And be compiling/running from the correct location.)

Answer (score 0):

For `javac` to automatically identify the correct path to all the Java source files, you would run it from directory `...\Diamond Hunter\src`, asking it to build the target file by its name relative to that path (`com\neet\DiamondHunter\Main\Game.java`).

Note, too, that this will *compile* the Java source code to Java bytecode.  To *run* the result you would, from the same directory, execute `java com.neet.DiamondHunter.Main.Game`.